# Handshake Problem $1978$ AMC $12$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> In a room containing $N$ people, $N > 3$, at least one person has not shaken hands with everyone else in the room. What is the maximum number of people in the room that could have shaken hands with everyone else ?

If there is a person that has not shaken hands with everyone else then what is the meaning of the question - **"What is the maximum number of people in the room that could have shaken hands with everyone else?**"

obviously the answer is $0$ (but this answer is incorrect),how can then there exist a person that has shaken hands with everyone else ?

Someone help understanding that what question is asking ?
thankyou

Comment: Consider the case of three people a,b,c. Say that b shook the hands of a and c. Then b shook the hands of everyone, but neither a nor c did.

Comment: "not shaken hands with everyone else in the room" may mean he or she has shaken hands with some.

Comment: N-2? That will be the case when N-2 persons have shaken hands to everyone but the remaining two have not shaken hands between them. N is not a possibility since a person exists by assumption. N-1 is similar, since if x has not shaken hands with y, then y has not shaken hands with everyone (because x exists). Does it make sense?

Comment: yes ,got it thanks